# User payment is successful, StoreKit return fails "paymentCancelled"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've implemented the `Non-renewing Subscriptions` IAP using `SwiftyStoreKit` library.

When the user tried to purchase subscription In the production environment sometimes it works properly but in some cases, user payment is successful but dramatically `StoreKit` return error `"paymentCancelled"` it the `SKError` class which means user canceled the request but user claims he did not cancel. Also customer proves that they paid

It failed in production but working in the sandbox.

Here's the method I used for purchase single product :

```swift
SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct("com.musevisions.SwiftyStoreKit.Purchase1", quantity: 1, atomically: false) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let product):
        // fetch content from your server, then:
        if product.needsFinishTransaction {
            SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
        }
        print("Purchase Success: \(product.productId)")
    case .error(let error):
        switch error.code {
        case .unknown: print("Unknown error. Please contact support")
        case .clientInvalid: print("Not allowed to make the payment")
        case .paymentCancelled: break
        case .paymentInvalid: print("The purchase identifier was invalid")
        case .paymentNotAllowed: print("The device is not allowed to make the payment")
        case .storeProductNotAvailable: print("The product is not available in the current storefront")
        case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: print("Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
        case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: print("Could not connect to the network")
        case .cloudServiceRevoked: print("User has revoked permission to use this cloud service")
        default: print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Your thoughts and suggestions highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In first sentence you mention a `non-renewing` in app purchase but then in the second sentence you state "User tried to renew subscription". It's not clear about what type product you are talking about.

Comment: @CemalEker I mean user manually renew the subscription after it’s expired.